# Regular expression to exclude chars for a valid URL

Tags: php, regex, validation, url-rewriting

I'd like to create a filter which allows almost all chars but without `/ < > ? =` 
I've read in some site, I shoud use the ^ char inside ranges, but if I try it doesn't work properly:

mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^(user/)([^\<\>\?=]+)([/]?)$    user.php?username=$2
```

php for validation:

```
return eregi ("[^\<\>\?=/]", $value);
```

how I shoud write to set the right filter to allow all chars but not `< > ? = /` in my range?

can someone sugest me some other character should not inserted on url string for security or compatibility?

consider I should work with URLs like:
`http://www.last.fm/music/小林武史`
`http://www.last.fm/music/Trentemøller`
`http://www.last.fm/music/Lindstrøm+&+Prins+Thomas`

Comment: Does your code not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough for both `mod_rewrite` PHP:

```
([^/<>?=]+)
```

BTW, you shouldn't use `eregi()` in PHP, use `preg_match()` instead with the `i` modifier.

Comment: You shouldn't escape the ? in the character class.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't think you need to escape all those characters in your character class. Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(user/)([^<>?=/]+)(/?)$    user.php?username=$2
```

Secondly, don't use eregi, it's crazy (and deprecated). Use preg_match instead:

```
return preg_match("|[^<>?=/]|", $value);
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

To put it in the colloquial, "ur doin it wrong". If you're not worrying about security *in your script* then no amount of blocking any characters will truly make your app secure short of cutting off the connection completely.